# for loop generates multiple plots

Tags: r, for-loop, plot

I have a question about  the for loop in combination with the plot function. 
I want to use a for loop function (see below) to plot multiple points in one plot. But my loop generates for each point his one plot. So with an i of 35 I generate 35 plot. My question is, is there a way to plot all the points in the same plot?

```
pdf("test plot.pdf")
for (i in 1:nrow(MYC)){
plot(MYC[i,1], MYC[i,2]
}
dev.off()
```

Thank you all!

Comment: The real data is a bit different! Here i could also use plot(MYC[,1], MYC[,1]) to get all the points in one plot. The loop in necesary!

Comment: Can you please expand the question to give a bit more detail on the type of plot you have in mind?  Can you provide some sample data?  Have you considered using facets in a single plot?

Comment: You want to use `points` instead of `plot`. Call `plot`, then `for` loop using points. Some situations even allow to have an `add` argument to `plot`, but I suspect that's not your case.

Comment: @Lisann In general I think it is a better strategy to do all your data aggregation before sending to plot.  In other words, use the loop to construct a `data.frame` or array with your data, then a single plot command to, say, `ggplot`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you are in essence trying to do multiple plots with a loop. R doesn't understand that actually want to plot only points. There's a cure for that, and it comes in vials of `points()`. Before calling a loop, construct your plot using the `type` argument. This will make an empty plot, something along the lines of:

```
plot(your.data, type = "n")
```

You can then use your loop (with `points`) to add points to this existing plot.